# Allowing numeric input in textfield doesn't work for first character

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Material UI phone number text field that only takes numbers.

```
//in helper function
export function allowNumbersOnly(input) {
    const formattedInput = input.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
    return formattedInput
}

//in component
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleUpdateField = this.handleUpdateField.bind(this)
}

handleUpdateField(field, value) {
    this.setState({
        [field]: value
    })
}

render() {
    <TextField floatingLabelText="Phone" value={phone} maxLength="10"
        onChange={(e) => this.handleUpdateField('phone', allowNumbersOnly(e.target.value))} />
}
```

In the `onChange` event handler, I'm passing in the new value that should only contain numbers, because any other input that isn't a number becomes an empty string. It works when I start typing a number (i.e. `798fff` would stop at `798` and any other input that's a non-number will not show); however, if I start the input with `f` and continue typing, i.e. `ff`, all of that gets recorded as input. [image]

I'm not sure if I've written my helper function incorrectly, or if I'm attaching the event handler wrong. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Try moving the helper call into the `handleUpdateField` function. I would write it as `value = allowNumbersOnly(value);`

Comment: I've figured it out - it had to do with the initial value of the text field.